# Unsuccessful Transaction for Malaysian eVisa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, payment-cards, malaysia, e-visas

I've been trying to apply for Malaysian tourist visa through [evisa link](https://malaysiavisa.imi.gov.my). Upon filling out all the fields and providing documents, I proceeded to payment using my SBI Platinum debit card (VISA card). However, upon entering otp it gives `Your transaction was unsuccessful, please check your details and try again.`

My intial guess was the same as suggested in the error message. But, this also happened when I carefully entered all the card details multiple times with both SBI and Deutsche bank debit card.

Question:

Any idea on what could be wrong and how to fix this?
Does the payment has to be through credit card or, debit card can be used?

Comment: Perhaps call your bank to see if they refused the transaction for fraud protection etc. purposes?

Comment: The issue still exists i'm trying for over a week to get this done. Does anyone else have a solution ?

Comment: @alex keep trying different credit cards. preferably a mastercard. That's the only solution in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Same happened to a friend of mine recently. He retried the transaction after 2-3 days and it went fine. It's probably a temporary issue.